# Navigation bar not appearing?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am currently using a form building library called
Eureka(https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka)  and for some reason
whenever I build a form,the navigation bar is not appearing eventhough
my view controller is embedded in a navigation controller and it is
set to visible.Any help?  Here's my repo:
https://github.com/ariff20/iTutor

**Code**

```
class SignUpViewController: FormViewController ,UINavigationBarDelegate{


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     let logButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "RightButtonTitle", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self,action: "multipleSelectorDone")

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logButton
     form +++ Section("Your Basic Details")
        <<< NameRow()
            {
                $0.placeholder = "Your Name"
            }
        <<< EmailRow()
            {
                $0.placeholder = "Email"
            }
        <<< PasswordRow()
            {
                $0.placeholder = "Password"
            }
        <<< PhoneRow()
            {
                $0.placeholder = "Your phone no,Customers will see this"
            }

        +++ Section("Select your Expertise")
        <<< MultipleSelectorRow<String>
            {
                $0.title = "Choose your Subjects"
                $0.options = ["English","Mandarin","Maths","Science","Bahasa Malaysia"]

            }
            .onPresent { from, to in
                to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: from, action:"multipleSelectorDone:")
        }
        <<< MultipleSelectorRow<String>
            {
                $0.title = "Choose your levels"
                $0.options = ["Standard 1-3","Standard 4-6","Form 1-3","Form 4-5"]

            }
            .onPresent { from, to in
                to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logButton}

        <<< MultipleSelectorRow<String>
            {
                $0.title = "Choose your pricing range"
                $0.options = ["RM30-RM40","RM40-RM60","RM60-RM80","RM80-RM100"]
            }
            .onPresent { from, to in
                to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logButton}
        +++ Section("Where can you teach?")
        <<< TextRow()
            {
                $0.placeholder = "State"
            }
        <<< TextRow()
            {
                $0.placeholder = "Town,ex:Near Shah Alam"
            }


    }
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden=false

}

func multipleSelectorDone(item:UIBarButtonItem)
{

    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

**OUTPUT**

1

[image]

2

[image]

3

[image]

Comment: No crazy formatting please. Thanks. ;)

Comment: Haha sorry bout that but it keeps saying that "it appears some of your code is not indented when all of it is clearly indented. Any ideas how to solve that ?

Comment: The problem was that all your post, code + sentences, was indented as a quote. Normal indentation: text. Four spaces: code. Between `\`\``: inline code. After `>`: quote. Usually, use Markdown and you'll be ok.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're presenting your ViewController like this:

```
let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TutorSignUp") as! SignUpViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

so your `SignUpViewController` doesn't actually have a `UINavigationController` as a parent.

This will fix that:

```
let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TutorSignUp") as! SignUpViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Amazing info!

Comment: Pushing a navigation controller is not supported

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 8.3+

Click on the view controller and select the following option:

Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need new `UINavigationBar` in StoryBoard then you will `@IBOutlet`

```
@IBOutlet weak var NavigationBar: UINavigationBar!
```

and you will `addSubvie`  UINavigationBar

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(NavigationBar)
```