# Swift 3 - Why is my Navigation Bar not showing?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a simple app to test push notifications of a rest api. I would like to show the Navigation Bars in the App but it is not working. In my AppDelegate I have the following code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.registerForPushNotifications()
    let url = "dev"
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(FFHelper.url(slug: url.slug()), forKey: "api-url")
    var vcString = "loginView"
    if KeychainSwift().get("auth-token") != nil {
        vcString = "notificationsTable"
    }
    let initialVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcString)
    initialVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    initialVC.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    window?.rootViewController = initialVC
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

In the Storyboard the navigation bar is enabled also:
[image]
Lastly, in the viewController, I do the same thing:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

But still after launching the app, the navigation bar ist not showing:
[image]
Can someone please tell me why this is?

Comment: This storyboard identifier ** var vcString = "loginView" ** is set for navigationController or for ViewController ?

Comment: How stupid I was... thank you for the hint. That's already enough to point out my stupidity... :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35460043/6550949 has the best answer on this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are showing vcString is  your `LoginVC`  ,

you need to use NavigationController identifier like `loginView`  or

You need to embded in `NavigationControler` before show

```
let initialVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcString)

    let navi =  UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: initialVC)
```

and

```
  window?.rootViewController = navi
```